# Design for all phones in android

Tags: android

I am totally confused here. I have two phones

**1. OnePlus 6
2. Nexus 6p**

Density, Size details below from phone:

**1+6:** DPI DisplayMetrics{density=2.625, width=1080, height=2154, scaledDensity=2.625, xdpi=403.411, ydpi=399.393} DENSITY 420

**Nexus 6P:** DPI DisplayMetrics{density=3.5, width=1440, height=2392, scaledDensity=4.025, xdpi=515.154, ydpi=516.063} DENSITY 560

I have developed a screen that shows up properly on 1+6 but few layouts in that same screen get cut in the bottom for Nexus 6P?

My question is that: The 6P has good resolution, everything is high but why can't it display everything similar to 1+6?

What could be wrong? How do I develop the app to show everything correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to optimize your app to be available to different devices.

**ScrollView**
This is the easiest way to show a screen with multiple contents on it.

**LinearLayout**
Aside from being the simplest ViewGroup subclass, the LinearLayout supports layout_weight for its children which sizes them depending on their layout weight and the attribute associated to them because of the orientation of their parent.

I Usually just use LinearLayout inside a ScrollView that optimizes layout_weight. This way if the linear layout's space is not enoungh, the scrollview will take care of the situation.

Comment: But I understand I have to use scrollView only on Parent Layout and can't be used on child right?

Comment: I'm not sure if i get you, but to answer what i think i understand. Yes, the parent view should be a scrollview and must have only one child. So, basically, you have to wrap your layout inside a scrollview

Comment: Hmm. I didn't understand the last point for LinearLayout: " I Usually just use ScrollView inside a LinearLayout that optimizes layout_weight. This way if the linear layout's space is not enoungh, the scrollview will take care of the situation."

Comment: Sorry for that, it should be LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. Edited the answer.